# Recursively gave sudo group to all files in var

Tags: linux, debian, permissions

On a Debian server, in a hastened move, we changed the permissions of the /var directory recursively so that sudo was the associated group, and with write privileges, with these commands:

```
chgrp -R sudo var/
chmod -R g+w var/
```

We realized after, that this was a very poor choice, but it's been done. What are the implications of doing this? Thank god this is just our dev server.

Comment: Lots of software will no longer have access to their files.  Possibly meaning they will crash/fail/corrupt the related data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services will misbehave or fail when they can't access their files.  Some will crash right away, and that plus the log files should make clear that it's because of a permission problem.  Others might only fail later, or misbehave in ways that might not be obvious right away.

/var is a big place.  It could take a while for all of the effects to show up.  I suggest reinstalling the essential services on that host, to let the installation scripts reset their permissions.

Comment: We ended up reinstalling the server and setting up the environment again

Comment: Ugh - sorry, but at least that fixed your problem for sure.

Comment: we had scripted a large part of our dev setup so in the end it was worth it/not too time consuming. I was just curious as to the implications when I asked. Thanks!